# data modeling to store the graph of interconnected nodes

Tags: database-design, graph, data-modeling

I am working on a project where we want to store the graph of interconnected nodes in DB in efficient manner.
For every node-node, we have a distance parameter "d". We want to store that too in DB.
So basically information we are storing is nodes, which nodes are interconnected and what is the distances between them. Later on our application need to query information like: what is distance between two given nodes, what are nodes which are at distance d from a particular node . It is small project for city routes.

I want to know what is the best DB and data model to be used for such kind of projects.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple ERD that could help you towards what you want to accomplish.

- Each node has a record in "node" table
- For every connection add a record to "node_connection" table with participating nodes along with the distance between them.

[image: simple ERD for node and node connection]

Comment: Thanks @Mevdiven. Thing is we are expecting a very large number of nodes close to 10000 within 2 months of application. And 1 node may or may not have 9999 connections to other nodes. So that was the reason I was not sure if simple and straightforward design as you mentioned above would work or not.

Comment: So basic inputs I want is for storing graphs(set of interconnected nodes) with very large number of data, do we rely on relational DB or non-SQL DB or anything else?

Comment: @ag112, this design will scale well even in case you end up with millions of nodes. You need to add more attributes for calculations that you mentioned. I suggest relational DBMS for your purpose. I used PostgreSQL for my own semi-scientific proof of concept project. It worked well and scaled to 50GB of complex data.